# Mason methods scope - override

Tags: perl, mason

Using [Mason2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason). Have 3 components.

```
/Base.mc
/tmp/Base.mc
/tmp/index.mc
```

The `/tmp/index.mc` with a content:

```
hello from <% $m->request_path %></br>
<% $.Some %>
```

the `$.Some` is an method defined in the `/Base.mc`:

```
<%augment wrap><% inner() %></%augment>

<%method Some>
The default "Some" method defined in the <% __PACKAGE__ %>
</%method>
```

the `/tmp/Base.mc` contains only

```
<%augment wrap><% inner() %></%augment>
```

Requesting `/tmp/index` prints:

```
hello from /tmp/index
The default "Some" method defined in the MC0::Base_mc
```

Now added the `Some` method into `/tmp/Base.mc`

```
<%method Some>
Redefined "Some" method in <% __PACKAGE__ %>
</%method>
```

Requesting `/tmp/index` again, it prints:

```
hello from /tmp/index
Redefined "Some" method in MC0::tmp_Base_mc
```

It honored the redefined `Some` method in the wrapped `/tmp/Base.mc`

The question is:

If Mason allows redefine methods as above, what is the purpose of the `<%override method>`? Does the `<%override Some>` something differently? (when i tested, it prints the same).

**EDIT** Maybe the question can be reduced to the following perl code.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

package My;
use Moose;
sub some { say "some from " . __PACKAGE__ }

package My2;
use Moose;
extends 'My';
sub some { say "another some from " . __PACKAGE__ }
#the above line is an correct way to refefine a sub "some"?
#so don;t need to use the
#override 'some' => sub { say "another some from " . __PACKAGE__ };

package main;
use My2;
my $m = My2->new();
$m->some();
```

in both cases (e.g. "plain" redefine and redefine with "override") prints:

```
another some from My2
```

So, the only difference is the possibility of calling the `super()` in the `some` with `override`? and sorry if I missed some basic knowlegde... ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`override` in Mason implements the method modifier `override` in Moose; Moose's `override` is syntactic sugar for the standard OO method for overriding a parent method, but with some restrictions if the method takes arguments. From the [Moose docs for `override`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::MethodModifiers#OVERRIDE-AND-SUPER):

> ```
> override 'display_name' => sub {
>     my $self = shift;
>     return super() . q{, } . $self->title(); };
> ```
>
> The call to `super()` is almost the same as calling
>   `$self->SUPER::display_name`. The difference is that the arguments
>   passed to the superclass's method will always be the same as the ones
>   passed to the method modifier, and cannot be changed. All arguments
>   passed to `super()` are ignored, as are any changes made to `@_` before
>   `super()` is called.

To give an example from your Moose classes above, let's give `some` some arguments:

```
package My;
use Moose;
sub some {
    my $self = shift;
    say "   " . __PACKAGE__ . " method 'some' args: " . join " ", @_;
}
```

Output after creating a `My` object and calling `$obj->some('pip', 'pop')`:

```
My method 'some' args: pip pop
```

Now let's look at My2. Define `some` as a normal package method:

```
package My2;
use Moose;
extends 'My';
sub some {
    my $self = shift;
    say "   # running 'some'";
    say "   " . __PACKAGE__ . " method 'some' args: " . join " ", @_;
    @_ = reverse @_;
    say "   # running \$self->SUPER::some with no args";
    $self->SUPER::some();
    say "   # running \$self->SUPER::some with reversed args";
    $self->SUPER::some( @_ );
    say "   # running super() with no args";
    super();
    say "   # running super() with reversed args";
    super( @_ );
};
```

Create a `My2` object, and call `$obj->some('pip','pop')`. Output:

```
# running 'some'
My2 method 'some' args: pip pop
# running $self->SUPER::some with no args
My method 'some' args: 
# running $self->SUPER::some with reversed args
My method 'some' args: pop pip
# running super() with no args
# running super() with reversed args
Arguments passed to super() are ignored at test.pl line 29.
```

Things to note:

- `super()` does nothing in a redefined method;
- `super()` cannot take arguments;
- `$self->SUPER::some` does not automatically get passed any arguments;
- arguments to `$self->SUPER::some` can be altered.

Now redefine the `some` method using `override`:

```
override 'some' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    say "   # running 'some'";
    say "   " . __PACKAGE__ . " method 'some' args: " . join " ", @_;
    @_ = reverse @_;
    say "   # running \$self->SUPER::some with no args";
    $self->SUPER::some();
    say "   # running \$self->SUPER::some with reversed args";
    $self->SUPER::some( @_ );
    say "   # running super() with no args";
    super();
    say "   # running super() with reversed args";
    super( @_ );
};
```

Output:

```
# running 'some'
My2 method 'some' args: pip pop
# running $self->SUPER::some with no args
My method 'some' args: 
# running $self->SUPER::some with reversed args
My method 'some' args: pop pip
# running super() with no args
My method 'some' args: pip pop
# running super() with reversed args
Arguments passed to super() are ignored at test.pl line 29.
My method 'some' args: pip pop
```

Things to note:

- the `super()` method now correctly calls the superclass method `some`;
- `super()` cannot take arguments; it automatically uses the same `@_` that you pass to the subclass method;
- arguments to `$self->SUPER::some` can be altered.

It is basically up to you how you implement methods in your subclasses, but this should have illustrated the differences between `override` and standard method redefinition.

Comment: So the only difference is: when using the `<%override...>` i can call the `<% super() %>`, but when simple redefine the method, i can't call the `<% super() %>`?

Comment: Edited the question - maybe it is more clear as `Mason`.

Comment: Very nice answer. (in the `My2` missing the `extend My;`) Reading the answer just realized what you said: `super() does nothing in a redefined method` - and this is confused me - with a simple redefine i should to call `shift->SUPER::some`. Thank you - very helpful.