# Multiple method overrides in Mason2

Tags: perl, mason

Building a website using [Mason2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason). Each page should call 3 filters (methods, called by content):

```
<% $.filter1(args...) {{ %>
<% $.filter2(args...) {{ %>
<% $.filter3(args...) {{ %>
```

I have 3 different implementation of those filters (methods). The default set of those 3 filters, are defined in the top level `/Base.mc` component.

Now, for a different parts of the site - (different routes), say for the

```
/a/all/paths>/...>
/b/.....
```

need use the above default set of filters/methods, but for another routes,

```
/c/...
/d/...
/e/...
```

need use another set of `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3` and for the

```
/x/....
/y/...
```

want use the third set.

The methods can be easily redefined, in lower level components, but doing it as in ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947199/mason-methods-scope-override)), isn't honors the DRY principe, e.g. in each

```
/c/Base.mc
/d/Base.mc
/e/Base.mc
```

Need repeat the same 3

```
<%override filter1>
...
<%override filter2>
...
<%override filter3>
```

The question is:

- how to write only once the 3 different implementations of the methods, and how to *use* them at once?

I tried make an compomponent, like: `/set2.mi`, `/set3.mi`, where I tried override those filter-methods, and called it in the needed `/{c,d,e}/Base.mc` as

```
<& /set2.mi &>
```

But this doesn't works.

How to write the 3 different methods implementatinons and call them  at once in the needed deeprr `Base.mc`? Is it possible?

In standard perl i would probably use *roles*, so in the needed packages I would use something like:

```
with 'Set1';
with 'Set2';
```

Where the packages `Set1` and `Set2` would contain the implementations of the needed methods, or for dynamic loading would use the `require ...` . Is something like possible in the Mason2, or i must repeat the `%ovverride`?

Hope this make sense... if not, please add an comment and i will try update the question.

**EDIT**

Example, for shorting the code, using only one filter not 3.

The `/Base.mc`

```
<%augment wrap><% inner() %></%augment>

% #this is the "default" MyHead filter
<%filter MyHead($arg)>
    <!-- in the real code it is more complicated, but for an illustration it is enough -->
    <h1 class="<% $arg %>"><% $yield->() %></h1>
</%filter>
```

When in the `/a/index.mc` using it as

```
% $.MyHead('big') {{
some head text
% }}
```

will output like:

```
<h1 class="big">some head text</h1>
```

now, have an another `MyHead`.

```
<%filter MyHead($arg)>
    <!-- in the real code it is more complicated - basically want output different thing -->
    <h2 id="<% $arg %>"><% $yield->() %></h2>
</%filter>
```

If I add the above code to my `/b/Base.mc` it will work, and calling the `MyHead` filter in the `/b/index.mc`

```
% $.MyHead('modal') {{
some other text
% }}
```

will call the redefined filter, and will output what i want

```
<h2 id="modal">some other text</h2>
```

The problem is,

- I don't want repeat the above filter code, in N other `Base.mc` components, like in `/c/Base.mc` and `/d/Base.mc` and so on.
- How to achieve, to write the filter once and "use" it in many other components for "redefine" the default one.

Comment: You say "I have 3 different implementation of those filters (methods). The default set of those 3 filters, are defined in the top level /Base.mc component." -- can you give an example of one of the filters and how it differs depending on the part of the site you're in?

Comment: @ialarmedalien added an example, hope make sense..

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be (not a nice one and produces an "spaghetty" like code) playing with the inheritance chain, as next:

1. Remove your "default" filter from the `/Base.mc`, so it would contains only the `<%augment wrap`
2. Create one component called for example: `BaseSetDefault.mc` and enter into it, your "default" filter and explicitly set the inheritance chain to the top level `/Base.mc`

```
<%augment wrap><% inner() %></%augment>

<%filter MyHead($arg)><h1 class="<% $arg %>"><% $yield->() %></h1></%filter>

<%flags>
    extends => '/Base.mc'
</%flags>
```

3. Similarly, create an another component say called as `/BaseSet2.mc` and put here your "Set2" filters, like:

```
<%augment wrap><% inner() %></%augment>

<%filter MyHead($arg)><h2 id="<% $arg %>"><% $yield->() %></h2></%filter>

<%flags>
    extends => '/Base.mc'
</%flags>
```

4. Now, in the `/a/Base.mc` and `/b/Base.mc` - everywhere, you want the "default" set, change the chain

```
<%flags>
    extends => '/BaseSetDefault.mc'
</%flags>
```

5. and in the `/c/Base.mc` and `/d/Base.mc` - everywhere you want the "Set2" filters, use the

```
<%flags>
    extends => '/BaseSet2.mc'
</%flags>
```

From now, the inheritance chain for `/c/index.mc` will be:

```
/c/index.mc -> /c/Base.mc -> /BaseSet2.mc -> /Base.mc
```

and the execution would be done as

```
/Base.mc -augment-> /BaseSet2.mc -augment-> /c/Base.mc -main-> /c/index.mc
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ - defines the Set2 filters
```

and for the `/a/index.mc` inheritance chain

```
/a/index.mc -> /a/Base.mc -> /BaseSetDefault.mc -> /Base.mc
```

the execution

```
/Base.mc -augment-> /BaseSetDefault.mc -augment-> /a/Base.mc -main-> /a/index.mc
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - defines the "Default" filters
```

It is not very nice solution, but works...